# Is it possible to run appium test on aws device farm with gradle command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automated-tests, appium, aws-device-farm

In yaml file below we are running with next command: `java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`.

Is it possible to run tests something like this `./gradlew clean runTests testng.xml`?

**version: 0.1

```
# Phases are collection of commands that get executed on Device Farm.
phases:
  # The install phase includes commands that install dependencies that your tests use.
  # Default dependencies for testing frameworks supported on Device Farm are already installed.
  install:
    commands:
      # This test execution environment uses Appium version 1.9.1 by default, however we enable you to change it using the Appium version manager (avm). An
      # example "avm" command below changes the version to 1.14.2.
      # For your convenience, we have preinstalled the following versions: 1.9.1, 1.10.1, 1.11.1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.15.1 or 1.16.0.
      # To use one of these Appium versions, change the version number in the "avm" command below to your desired version:
      - export APPIUM_VERSION=1.14.2
      - avm $APPIUM_VERSION
      - ln -s /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/.bin/appium  /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js

  # The pre-test phase includes commands that setup your test environment.
  pre_test:
    commands:
      # Setup environment variables for java
      - export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DEVICEFARM_TESTNG_JAR
      - export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/*
      - export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/dependency-jars/*
      # We recommend starting appium server process in the background using the command below.
      # Appium server log will go to $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR directory.
      # The environment variables below will be auto-populated during run time.
      - echo "Start appium server"
      - >-
        appium --log-timestamp
        --default-capabilities "{\"deviceName\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME\", \"platformName\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\",
        \"app\":\"$DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH\", \"udid\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID\", \"platformVersion\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\",
        \"chromedriverExecutable\":\"$DEVICEFARM_CHROMEDRIVER_EXECUTABLE\"}"
        >> $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt 2>&1 &

      - >-
        start_appium_timeout=0;
        while [ true ];
        do
            if [ $start_appium_timeout -gt 60 ];
            then
                echo "appium server never started in 60 seconds. Exiting";
                exit 1;
            fi;
            grep -i "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723" $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt >> /dev/null 2>&1;
            if [ $? -eq 0 ];
            then
                echo "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723";
                break;
            else
                echo "Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second";
                sleep 1;
                start_appium_timeout=$((start_appium_timeout+1));
            fi;
        done;

  # The test phase includes commands that start your test suite execution.
  test:
    commands:
      # Your test package is downloaded in $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH so we first change directory to that path.
      - echo "Navigate to test package directory"
      - echo $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH

      # By default, the following command is used by Device Farm to run your Appium TestNG test.
      # The goal is to run to your tests jar file with all the dependencies jars in the CLASSPATH.
      # Alternatively, You may specify your customized command.
      # Note: For most use cases, the default command works fine.
      # Please refer "http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng" for more options on running TestNG tests from the command line.
      - echo "Unzipping TestNG tests jar"
      - unzip tests.jar
      - echo "Start Appium TestNG test"
      - cd suites
      - ls -l
      - java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
  # The post test phase includes are commands that are run after your tests are executed.
  post_test:
    commands:
    - ls -l
    - zip -r allure.zip allure-results artifacts report test-output
    - ls -l
    - cp allure.zip $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR
    - cd $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR
    - ls -l

# The artifacts phase lets you specify the location where your tests logs, device logs will be stored.
# And also let you specify the location of your test logs and artifacts which you want to be collected by Device Farm.
# These logs and artifacts will be available through ListArtifacts API in Device Farm.
artifacts:
  # By default, Device Farm will collect your artifacts from following directories
  - $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR**
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out. Are you trying to replace "java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml" with "./gradlew clean runTests testng.xml", or expecting to run gradle command locally?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help because when we select Appium TestNG config we can upload only dependencies on farm and parser forbid to go to next step

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

1. You need to zip all project with your build.gradle files
2. Select Appium Node config, upload your zip
3. Use yaml config from TestNg or from my question, but replace command *java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml* to *./gradlew clean runTests(task in your gradle) your_test_suite.xml*